# List of M365 applications like MyApps

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing a .Net Core 6 application where authentication is done using Microsoft Identity. I'd need to list M365 applications of my user in a web page as in https://myapps.microsoft.com/

I have combined many results of different MSGraph API and I obtained over 180 result. But none show me something about MSApp like Excel, Visio , Engage, Word , etc.

These are the different MSGraph APIs I combined:

- graphClient.Applications
- graphClientBeta.ServicePrincipals
- graphClient.Users[ userId ].AppRoleAssignments
- graphClient.Users[ userId ].AssignedLicenses
- graphClient.Users[ userId ].LicenseDetails

and for every groups of which userId is member:

- graphClient.Groups[ group.Id ].AppRoleAssignments

How can I do this? And are there other ways without using MSGraphAPI?

Thanks for any suggestions!